# How to Remove External Directory during uninstall macos x

Tags: macos, javafx, native, uninstallation, packaging

I've created the application and installed it. When i start the application, it creates the directory in user home. When i uninstall the application in /Application/App-Name, the folder still remains. It'll affect my updated version. So Can Anybody share How to delete the directory along with uninstalling the application.

Thanks

Comment: Did you wrote the uninstall routine?

Comment: I have a feeling the O.P. wants to detect when the end user drags his app into the trash can.

Comment: How to write the uninstall routine. Can you share the procedure to write it.